# How can I get average number in an array contain string and number

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

I'm writing a function to pass the test that have array contains number and string.

Here is the test cases `average-numner.test.js`:

```
var average = require("./get-average");

test("Average", function() {
  var numbers = [4, "-", 8, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2];
  var expected = 5;

  var output = average(numbers);

  expect(output).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Here is the function that I wrote `average-number.js`:

```js
// the input is an array of numbers and strings
// return the average of all the numbers
// be sure to exclude the strings
function averageNumbers(str) {
  let sum = 0;
  let newArr = [];
  var filtered = str.filter(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item);
  });
  return filtered;
}

console.log(averageNumbers([4, "-", 8, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2]));

//    module.exports = averageNumbers;
```

I achieved that I got new array with only number but it still have string `"57"` in my `filtered` array. How can I get rid of it and find sum to get average number?

Comment: I made a snippet. You need to return filtered to console log it

Comment: _'...but it still have string "57"'_ - Why do you expect `.filter()` to change the types of the elements in `str` (which is a terrible name)?

Comment: Notice that the `filter()` doesn't actually convert the elements, it simply tests whether it could.

Comment: @mplungjan _"...with only number but it still have string "57""_ - What does returning `filtered` change on the actual problem?

Comment: @pilchard even then, it will reject values like `0` or accept values like `"1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map and filter

Note I changed the variable name str to arr since it is not a string.

I test for type and whether or not the number is finite and added the rest of the calculation

The code now returns the expected `5`

```js
// the input is an array of numbers and strings
// return the average of all the numbers
// be sure to exclude the strings
function averageNumbers(arr) {
  const filtered = arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'number' && isFinite(item))
  const sum = filtered.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
  return +parseFloat(sum/filtered.length).toPrecision(12); // this can be ugly
}

console.log(averageNumbers([4, "-", 8, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2]));
console.log(averageNumbers([3, "-", 4, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2, 3]));
```

Just a reduce returning an object to see the sub parts

```js
// the input is an array of numbers and strings
// return the average of all the numbers
// be sure to exclude the strings
const averageNumbers = arr => {
  const averageObject = arr.reduce((acc,item,i) => {
    if (typeof item === 'number' && isFinite(item)) {
      acc.sum+=item;
      acc.nofItems++;
    }  
    if (i===arr.length-1) acc.average = acc.sum/acc.nofItems;
    return acc;
  },{sum:0,nofItems:0, average:0})
  return averageObject;
}  

const ave1 = averageNumbers([4, "-", 8, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2]);
console.log(`Average of ${ave1.nofItems} numeric items was ${ave1.average}. The sum was ${ave1.sum}`) 
const ave2 = averageNumbers([3, "-", 4, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2, 3]);
console.log(`Average of ${ave2.nofItems} numeric items was ${ave2.average}. The sum was ${ave2.sum}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function averageNumbers(arr) {
  var filter = arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'number');
  var sum = filter.reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0);
  return sum / filter.length;
}

console.log(averageNumbers([4, "-", 8, 11, "hello", "57", 0, 2]));

//    module.exports = averageNumbers;
```

Which gives you expected `5`

Answer (score 1):

`filter` only checks if the condition is truthy for the given element, and keeps it if so. But it keeps the original value, not the output of the predicate function. If all you want to be able to do is sum the numbers, this should work:

```
var filtered = str.filter(function (item) {
    return parseInt(item);
  }).map(item => parseInt(item));
```

However, if a number is parsed as a `0`, it will be considered falsy and filter will drop it. That's okay for computing a sum, because the `0` makes no difference, but if you want to keep it you can do something like:

```
const filtered = str.map(item => parseInt(item))
    .filter(item => item !== NaN);
```

This will attempt to parse all values, and keep only the values that successfully parse, including existing integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and inside callback use `typeof` to check if the element is a number of not. The accumulator object consist of three keys, total,count and average.

```js
function averageNumbers(c) {
  return c.reduce(function(a, b) {
    "number" === typeof b && (a.total += b, a.count += 1, a.average = a.total / a.count);
    return a;
  }, {
    total: 0,
    count: 0,
    average: 0
  }).average;
};

console.log(averageNumbers([4, '-', 8, 11, 'hello', '57', 0, 2]));
```

Comment: It looks like you only parse the number if it's already a number. Wouldn't you want to do the opposite? If it's a number, just add it. If not, try to parse it, and add it if successful.

Comment: @Henrik actually dont need to parse at all. Forgot to remove `parse` after previous edit